# What's the difference between the various misc-fixed fonts of the same size and same ISO code?

Tags: x11, fonts

Consider the [misc-fixed font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_(typeface)) 5x7 with ISO 8859. On my platform, in `/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc`, there's a bunch of `.pcf` files for this font:

```
5x7-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz
5x7-ISO8859-10.pcf.gz
5x7-ISO8859-13.pcf.gz
5x7-ISO8859-14.pcf.gz
5x7-ISO8859-15.pcf.gz
5x7-ISO8859-16.pcf.gz
5x7-ISO8859-2.pcf.gz
5x7-ISO8859-3.pcf.gz
5x7-ISO8859-4.pcf.gz
5x7-ISO8859-5.pcf.gz
5x7-ISO8859-7.pcf.gz
5x7-ISO8859-8.pcf.gz
5x7-ISO8859-9.pcf.gz
```

And, in the `fonts.dir` file, there's the following 'aliases':

```
5x7-ISO8859-1.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-1
5x7-ISO8859-10.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-10
5x7-ISO8859-13.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-13
5x7-ISO8859-14.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-14
5x7-ISO8859-15.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-15
5x7-ISO8859-16.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-16
5x7-ISO8859-2.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-2
5x7-ISO8859-3.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-3
5x7-ISO8859-4.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-4
5x7-ISO8859-5.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-5
5x7-ISO8859-7.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-7
5x7-ISO8859-8.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-8
5x7-ISO8859-9.pcf.gz -misc-fixed-medium-r-normal--7-70-75-75-c-50-iso8859-9
```

What's the difference between the `.pcf` files? Are they different fonts? Do they have different characters? Or are they the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They’re all different encodings: [ISO 8859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) parts 1 through 16. The first half (or slightly more) of the fonts should be identical, the second will vary from one encoding to another; there’s [a handy comparison table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859#Table) on Wikipedia.